# Issue deleting a canvas object from class

Tags: python, class, canvas

I have a problem with deleting canvas object from class.

I created an object of type `Rectangle` called `f`. Then I need to delete this object. Python deletes `f`, but does not delete a canvas object, which is on Frame. I don't know where is the problem.

```
from tkinter import *


class Rectangle():

    def __init__(self, coords, color):   
        self.coords = coords
        self.color = color   

    def __del__(self):
        print("In DELETE")
        del self
        print("Goodbye")

    def draw(self, canvas):
        """Draw the rectangle on a Tk Canvas."""
        print("In draw ")
        print("Canvas  =  ",canvas)
        print("self = ",self)
        print("bild canvas = ",canvas.create_rectangle(*self.coords, fill=self.color))


root = Tk()
root.title('Basic Tkinter straight line')
w = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)

f = []
f = Rectangle((0+30*10, 0+30*10, 100+30*10, 100+30*10), "yellow")
print("Draw object", f.draw(w), f)
f.__del__()
del f

w.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: The Canvas object is assigned to the reference w.  Is that what you want to delete?

Comment: yes, if I do w.delete(f) nothing happend

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem you are having is you started creating a `Rectangle` object for your own use, which seems reasonable, but you need to work on its implementation.

Anyways to accomplish what you want to do simply (without your object):

```
# draws a rectangle and returns a integer
rectangle_id = c.create_rectangle(*(0, 0, 30, 30), fill="yellow")
c.delete(rectangle_id) # removes it from the canvas
```

To accomplish what you want with your `Rectangle` object I suggest using an attribute to store the id when you drew it and implement a method that can delete it. It looks like you may want to use the `__del__` method to remove it when there are no longer any references to your object.  This can be done, but you should be aware of some caveats (outside of the scope of my answer... See: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/).  I personally would opt for explicitly calling a method to delete the object representation from the view to avoid all that nonsense :).

There are many design decisions here I am ignoring, I suggest you put some thought into your use of OO here, or avoid it until you have better understanding of tkinter.

Comment: I created a self.rectangle_id in class Rectangle and the problem disappear,Thanks very much, Happy new year